# Pasar elementos html a INPUT DE FORM POR AJAX Y JAVASCRIPT

Tags: php, javascript

modifico la pregunta, ya tengo los datos en consola y preparados para pasarlos por ajax a modal. y ahora me lanza error de Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<script>
$('#editProductModal').on('show.bs.modal',$(function(llevar){
var idValueQueNecesito = $('#order').text();
console.log(idValueQueNecesito);
}));

   $.ajax({
     method: "POST",
     url: "html/modal_edit.php",
     data: idValueQueNecesito,
     dataType: "json"
     }).done(function(data){
     order(data);
     $("input[edit_id_orden]").text(data[0].edit_id_orden)
    });
```

elemento html

```
 <table id="table1" class='table table-responsive'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope='col'>Nro.Orden</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tdoby>
            <tr>  
              <td id="order"><?= $_SESSION['id_order'];?></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

lo que genera ese id order

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="id_recolector" placeholder="ID recolector" style="float:right;width:150px;height:40px;" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['id_recolector']))
                        { echo $_SESSION['id_recolector']; } ?>" readonly="readonly">
```

Generar Orden

y el modal dond quiero que aparezca

```
   <div id="editProductModal" class="modal fade">
    <input type="text" name="edit_id_orden" id="valueQueNecesito" 
    class="form-control" required>
   </div>
```

y esto es lo que he intentado, y me da erro de token o undifenido

```
       <script>
          $('#editProductModal').on('show.bs.modal', (function (ll 
          evar){(
          var valueQueNecesito = $('#order').text(); 
          console.log(valueQueNecesito);  
          });

    $.ajax({
       method:"POST",
       url: "html/modal_edit.php",
       data: parametros,
       dataType : "json"
        }).done(function(data){
       order(data);
       $("input[edit_id_orden]").text(data[0].edit_id_orden)

           });   
      <script>
```

puede ser que tenga algunos errores de sintaxtis, pero realmente no llego a conseguir la logica 
   para enviar ese parametro al modal que quiero que reciba los datos en el input name="id_orden",
   les agradeceria algun comentario o recomendacion. gracias

Comment: Sé más especifico, quieres el dato en el input del modal pero en que momento o que?, cuando de click, al cargar la página. Hay solo 1 valor, hay varios valores, son muchos factores a tomar en cuenta.

Comment: al hacer click en un una imagen de un <i> que esta adentro de un <td> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-up">Recuperar</i></a></td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que al dar click en el td pase el valor directo al modal entonces lo que tienes que hacer es utilizar el evento click, jalar el valor del text y pasarlo directamente al input, de la siguiente manera:

**Actualización:**

Agregando el enlace de **Recuperar** utilizas el mismo método, pero para que tome el valor de la misma linea tienes que hacer uso de `closest("tr")` para tomar toda la linea y con `find(".order")` buscar la columna que tenga la clase `order` y extraer el `text()`.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.fas', function () {
    $('#valueQueNecesito').val($(this).closest("tr").find(".order").text());
    $('#editProductModal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9c387cc991.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table id="table1" class='table table-responsive'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope='col'>Serie</th>
        <th scope='col'>Nro.Orden</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"> Recuperar</i></a></td>
        <td class="order">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"> Recuperar</i></a></td>
        <td class="order">2</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="editProductModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="text" name="edit_id_orden" id="valueQueNecesito" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: esta excelente tu respuesta eduar javier maldonado. Pero no necesito darle click a la orden. Necesito es al darle click a la imagen <td> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-up">Recuperar</i></a></td> RECUPERAR. => es la que abre el modal donde quiero que se inserte automaticamente el valor.

Comment: ¿Pero esa imagen está en otra columna de la misma linea?

Comment: No, esa imagen esta en otro fichero, que esta llamado desde un ajax. No esta en la misma tabla. Se llama al realizar una consulta de datos en la misma vista, pero es otro fichero que es llamado por ajax.

Comment: Ya no comprendí, deberías ser más especifico en el planteamiento de tu problema. O edita tu pregunta y replantéala a detalle para poderte dar una respuesta más acorde a lo que necesitas. Porque no tengo idea de que hace tu archivo modal_edit.php, no se lo que retorna, no muestra donde armas el arreglo de parámetros que estás enviando por ajax. Sé más explicito, da más detalles y podremos ayudarte con tu problema en concreto, porque ni eso de la imagen lo muestras en la pregunta y no comprendo eso de que está en otro fichero es confuso.

Comment: tengo el fichero datoscliente.php => el cual tiene incluido todos los modal. A su vez en el fichero datosclientes.php
tengo el formulario donde ingreso un dato y me genera una orden y lo imprime en la tabla. esa orden imprimida en la tablal
la capturo y necesito llevar al modal edit produc, que se me abre al ahcer click en recuperar. Recuperar 
se despliega al hacer una consulta en el buscador interno arriba del cuadro enviarcliente. se despliguea cuando
consulto la base de datos, y en el resultado de la consulta me sale la imagen para  hacer un update a ese registro

Comment: Si tenía razón en cuanto a que la el RECUPERAR estaba en la misma linea del TD, ya actualice la respuesta, ejecuta el ejemplo.

Comment: es mi responsabilidad no ser especifico. ese id orden, 
 es otra tabla que esta en en el fichero datoscliente.php, lo cual solo genera un nro de orden. el recuperar, esta en otra tabla. que tambien tiene como campo id_orden, pero es totalmente diferente porque es otra tabla. la tabla dond solo se imprime el nro de orden, ese numero de orden se inserta en tabla ORDENES, y la otra tabla donde esta recuperar, identificacion,serie,id_orden, eso hace un update a la tabla EXPRESS. con datos del modal. donde quiero q en el input id_orden del modal, aparezca la orden de la primera tabla enpanalla

Comment: ya añadi otra foto. donde se encuentra la tabla unica nro orden